# What happens to the breast milk of a mother who doesn't nurse

Tags: breastfeeding, female, absorption-absorb, breast-milk, postpartum-body

Say the baby dies, what happens to the milk? Is it re-absorbed by the body and will the absorption of the macro and micro nutrient be same as someone who would drink it. I do know that cows are prone to health problems if they are not milked but they were specifically bred to produce milk so drawing parallel conclusion might not work...

Got curious after seeing a click-bait article about a woman surviving in the forest using her breast milk. I did not read the article so I assumed she must have drank it.

Comment: You mentioned that cows are prone to health problems if they are not milked but they are specifically bred to produce milk.  I am not totally in agreement on the breeding argument and that is off-topic anyway, but one health problem they have matches humans.  Chronic mastitis occurs in women who are not breastfeeding https://www.webmd.com/women/guide/breast-infection

Comment: What books have you read or internet searching have you done on the subject?

Comment: Here is an open textbook with literature on lactation: http://library.open.oregonstate.edu/aandp/chapter/28-6-lactation/